# Xcode 12.1, disabled Bundle Identifier <Multiple Values> field, Flutter App

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase-authentication, bundle-identifier

**Problem**
I am having an issue with one of my Xcode projects (Flutter App) when incorporating Firebase Authorization into it. I need to be able to set the Bundle Identifier (in General tab, of Runner) as part of the Firebase configuration, unfortunately the field itself is "disabled".
I can not: click into it, tab in, nor update it via the info.plist file, nor update it via the Info tab.
I can: make changes to the info.plist field and the Info tab Bundle Identifier field, but they do not change/update the General tab Bundle Identifier. It remains a constant:

Bundle Identifier:

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue? Or some troubleshooting to try?

**Stats/Details:**
Android Studio: version 4.1
Xcode: version 12.1
MacOS Catalina: 10.15.7
Firebase Auth: latest version Nov 07 2020

Other projects on Xcode do not have this problem, only this specific project is having this issue and only this project uses Firebase, however this field was disabled before I went to add Firebase.
[Info.plist screen with Bundle Identifier field default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zts9P.png)
[General tab with Bundle Identifier field disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWhT3.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can try with below steps for updating bundle identifier,

- project/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
- right click-> Show package contents
- click project.pbxproj
- Search for "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "
- set bundle identifier value there
- flutter clean

Comment: Hey @Ameer, thank you very much for the reply. This fix wasn't quite where my problem was, it was based in calling Firebase configure twice (once by default once by me) and having mismatching Bundle Identifiers. But your suggestion very much so pointed me in the correct direction! It lead to having a real error print out that I could figure it out from there. Again, thank you.

Comment: **Fix** I looked in the project.pbxproj as suggested, found the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER and it was already set but not to what I thought it should be, I left it as is. Then I ran the project in Xcode and printed the Bundle Identifier in the App Delegate Swift File, found the name discrepancy. Next, deleted the ios config in Firebase and remade a new one with the correct bundle identifier. Everything worked from there.

Comment: @BlackRabbit12, u can post this as an answer instead of a comment. It will help who quickly walkthrough for answers.

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Studio Code, similar to Ameer, with minor changes, this didn't happen because of firebase, so might not be the full solution to the  issue above.

1. goto folder project/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
2. open folder and then click project.pbxproj
3. I searched for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER, there where three, one for debug, profile and release.
4. update the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER to be what it should be, as per appstoreconnect.apple.com (or if you have what every you want if you haven't done the apple store bundle setup yet)
5. saved changed, and open in xcode and all was good :)

(note - I would have put a comment but I'm not allowed to)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all bundle identifiers are the same (you may find that you've misspelled a letter in one of these PROJECT_NAME_INDETIFIERS or one letter is not the same as the other in another field).